# Block of code with no spacing or indentation

Tags: html

I have received a html block of code (email template so lots of tables) that I have to work with that has no spacing or indentation aand is essentially all on one line. It's a nightmare to try and edit it.

Does anyone know of any online tools or applications that you can copy and paste code into where it organises it for you?

```
olor="#e5e5e5" alink="#000000" class="yfix" leftmargin="0" rightmargin="0" topmargin="0"> <!--//-->      <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"> <tr> <td width="100%" valign="top" bgcolor="#e5e5e5" align="center"> <table width="698" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"> <tr> <td width="5"><img hspace="0" height="1" width="5" src="http://info.page7media.ie/img/trans.gif" /></td> <td align="left"> <table width="688" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"> <tr> <td height="10"><a name="top_of_mail"></a></td> </tr> <tr> <td align="center"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="2" color="red" style="font-size: 12px; line-height: 17px;">If you are unable to see this message, click <a target="_blank" href="http://info.page7media.ie/u/gm.php?UID=JJ20yz3nz2&ID=279438389_478447_36061" style="text-decoration: underline;"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-seri
```

Comment: Now you know how we feel.

Comment: There are a lot of them https://www.google.ru/#q=prettify+html

Comment: worth noting your code example here is cut off at the beginning.

Comment: one of the most widely used code sharing site is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), just paste the code, click `TidyUp` and it will do the job for you ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Dirty Markup, it cleaned this markup up nicely

http://www.dirtymarkup.com/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    olor="#e5e5e5" alink="#000000" class="yfix" leftmargin="0" rightmargin="0"
    topmargin="0"&gt; <!--//-->

    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td align="center" style="background-color: #E5E5E5" valign="top"
            width="100%">
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="698">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="5"><img height="1" hspace="0" src=
                        "http://info.page7media.ie/img/trans.gif" width=
                        "5"></td>

                        <td align="left">
                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"
                            width="688">
                                <tr>
                                    <td height="10">
                                        <a id="top_of_mail" name=
                                        "top_of_mail"></a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center">
                                        If you are unable to see this message,
                                        click <a href=
                                        "http://info.page7media.ie/u/gm.php?UID=JJ20yz3nz2&ID=279438389_478447_36061"
                                        style="text-decoration: underline;"
                                        target="_blank"></a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for something called a "beautifier".

Here's an online beautifier that supports HTML: http://ctrlq.org/beautifier/

I beautified it for you but noticed the beginning of your code sample is missing.

```
olor="#e5e5e5" alink="#000000" class="yfix" leftmargin="0" rightmargin="0" topmargin="0">

<!--//-->

<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">

  <tr>

    <td width="100%" valign="top" bgcolor="#e5e5e5" align="center">

      <table width="698" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">

        <tr>

          <td width="5">
            <img hspace="0" height="1" width="5" src="http://info.page7media.ie/img/trans.gif" />
          </td>

          <td align="left">

            <table width="688" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">

              <tr>

                <td height="10">
                  <a name="top_of_mail">
                  </a>
                </td>

              </tr>

              <tr>

                <td align="center">
                  <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="2" color="red" style="font-size: 12px; line-height: 17px;">
                    If you are unable to see this message, click 
                    <a target="_blank" href="http://info.page7media.ie/u/gm.php?UID=JJ20yz3nz2&ID=279438389_478447_36061" style="text-decoration: underline;">
                      <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-seri
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an online code formatter.

http://ctrlq.org/beautifier/

I grabbed the first one that looked interesting.  There are others out there.

http://bit.ly/1Eqgeqr